# What wrong with `(A.array() == A.array()).matrix()`?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, eigen

This is my code:

```
   MatrixXd A(3,3);
   A<<1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
   MatrixXd b(3,3);
   b = (A.array() == A.array()).matrix();
   cout<<b<<endl;
```

It show that something wrong with `(A.array() == A.array()).matrix()`.
This is the error message:

```
In file included from /home/biss/Desktop/self-driving-car/term2/kalman-Filter/Eigen/Core:254:0,
                 from /home/biss/Desktop/self-driving-car/term2/kalman-Filter/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /home/biss/Desktop/self-driving-car/term2/kalman-Filter/cpp_normal_op/clion_c/main.cpp:2:
/home/biss/Desktop/self-driving-car/term2/kalman-Filter/Eigen/src/Core/Assign.h: In instantiation of ‘Derived& Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>::lazyAssign(const Eigen::DenseBase<OtherDerived>&) [with OtherDerived = Eigen::MatrixWrapper<const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_cmp_op<double, (Eigen::internal::ComparisonName)0u>, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > > >; Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>]’:
/home/biss/Desktop/self-driving-car/term2/kalman-Filter/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:414:30:   required from ‘Derived& Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::lazyAssign(const Eigen::DenseBase<OtherDerived>&) [with OtherDerived = Eigen::MatrixWrapper<const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_cmp_op<double, (Eigen::internal::ComparisonName)0u>, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > > >; Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>]’
/home/biss/Desktop/self-driving-car/term2/kalman-Filter/Eigen/src/Core/Assign.h:527:123:   required from ‘static Derived& Eigen::internal::assign_selector<Derived, OtherDerived, false, false>::run(Derived&, const OtherDerived&) [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; OtherDerived = Eigen::MatrixWrapper<const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_cmp_op<double, (Eigen::internal::ComparisonName)0u>, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > > >]’
/home/biss/Desktop/self-driving-car/term2/kalman-Filter/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:653:72:   required from ‘Derived& Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::_set_noalias(const Eigen::DenseBase<OtherDerived>&) [with OtherDerived = Eigen::MatrixWrapper<const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_cmp_op<double, (Eigen::internal::ComparisonName)0u>, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > > >; Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>]’
/home/biss/Desktop/self-driving-car/term2/kalman-Filter/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:638:114:   required from ‘void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::_set_selector(const OtherDerived&, const Eigen::internal::false_type&) [with OtherDerived = Eigen::MatrixWrapper<const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_cmp_op<double, (Eigen::internal::ComparisonName)0u>, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > > >; Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>]’
/home/biss/Desktop/self-driving-car/term2/kalman-Filter/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:630:20:   required from ‘Derived& Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::_set(const Eigen::DenseBase<OtherDerived>&) [with OtherDerived = Eigen::MatrixWrapper<const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_cmp_op<double, (Eigen::internal::ComparisonName)0u>, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > > >; Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>]’
/home/biss/Desktop/self-driving-car/term2/kalman-Filter/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:172:24:   required from ‘Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>& Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>::operator=(const Eigen::MatrixBase<OtherDerived>&) [with OtherDerived = Eigen::MatrixWrapper<const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_cmp_op<double, (Eigen::internal::ComparisonName)0u>, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > > >; _Scalar = double; int _Rows = -1; int _Cols = -1; int _Options = 0; int _MaxRows = -1; int _MaxCols = -1]’
/home/biss/Desktop/self-driving-car/term2/kalman-Filter/cpp_normal_op/clion_c/main.cpp:23:7:   required from here
/home/biss/Desktop/self-driving-car/term2/kalman-Filter/Eigen/src/Core/util/StaticAssert.h:32:40: error: static assertion failed: YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY
     #define EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(X,MSG) static_assert(X,#MSG);
                                        ^
/home/biss/Desktop/self-driving-car/term2/kalman-Filter/Eigen/src/Core/Assign.h:500:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT’
   EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(SameType,YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY)
   ^
CMakeFiles/clion_c.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/clion_c.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/clion_c.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/clion_c.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/clion_c.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/clion_c.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/clion_c.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'clion_c' failed
make: *** [clion_c] Error 2
```

However, If I change my code:

```
   MatrixXd A(3,3);
   A<<1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
   MatrixXd b(3,3);
   b = (A.array() * A.array()).matrix();
   cout<<b<<endl;
```

It can run ok.

```
 1  4  9
16 25 36
49 64 81
```

If I want to do this operation:`(A.array() == A.array()).matrix()`, what should I do?

Comment: *It show that something wrong with (A.array() == A.array()).matrix()* -- What is *It*?  And why not simply post the error message?

Comment: Are you an alien testing the human telepathic abilities?

Comment: Show your error informations ~

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do ? ( A.array() == A.array()) seems to be a simple check to me that will return true. What matrix are you attempting to retrieve here ?

Comment: @VishaalShankar, While I don't have much familiarity with Eigen, I presume it produces an element-wise equality matrix.

Comment: Sorry, everyone. I update the error message

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: I want to retrieve this matrix `A.array() *-== A.array()` @VishaalShankar

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to get the result from `A.array() * A.array()`. However, it was wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets break it down a bit. `(A.array() == A.array())` represents the (2D) array with a boolean showing element-wise equality. If you were to write

```
std::cout << (A.array() == A.array());
```

you would get

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

as you're asking if `A` equals itself and it happens not to have any NANs. The error message that you got says `error: static assertion failed: YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY`. Which means exactly that. You cannot assign a `MatrixXf` to a `MatrixXd` either. There is no implicit casting. So, to make it work, you want to write

```
   b = (A.array() == A.array()).cast<double>().matrix();
```

which explicitly casts the booleans to doubles. I'm pretty sure that's not exactly what you want to do, but that is what is written in you're question (hopefully because it's an incomplete MCVE).

Comment: Btw: The `.matrix()` is optional here. And you can alternatively write: `A.cwiseEqual(A).cast<double>()` or `(!A.array().isNaN()).cast<double>()`.

Comment: @chtz I fully concur.